# How to replay html audio in slow speed?

Tags: html

it's a dictionary, i want the play button of the word to play the audio first in normal speed and then (or on second click) in slow play rate (say 0.75)
is there a way to do that

```
<script>function abarticulation(){var music = new Audio('new folder/abarticulation.mp3');   music.play()                
;}
</script><input type="button" value=  onclick="abarticulation()" />
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: thanks. for the quistion asked, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling audio speed of a mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618845/controlling-audio-speed-of-a-mp3-file)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No, the audio in the example above is loaded through javascript, and it's not HTML selector

Comment: @user3840170 Hi, sorry to intrude, i saw some of your other answers, you seem an expert in audio, can you help

Comment: see the accepted answer in the dupe, its javascript, all you need do is `music.playbackRate=0.5`, its a dupe no point repeating answers just to change `myaudio` var to `music`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myaudio=document.getElementById("audio1");
myaudio.playbackRate=0.5;
```

Comment: the audio in the example above is not an Html selector but loaded through javascript