# How to sync multiple audio progress with progress bar so that when all audio completes progress goes to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to sync my progress bar based on sound played having multiple sound tracks.

At a time, I can have 2 sound tracks of different languages that I need to sync with my progress bar even considering network lag.

Problem: sync is not happening between all playing audios and progress bar.

Please provide me best algorithm for the same.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
const range = document.getElementById("range");

let soundTracks = [{id:1,sound:"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/dosimeter_alarm.ogg"},{id:2,sound:"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/phone_alerts_and_rings.ogg"},{id:3, sound:"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/animals/afternoon_crickets_long.ogg"},{id:4, sound:"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/medium_bell_ringing_near.ogg"}];

let allSoundLoaded = [] , sounds = [], progress = 0;

function handleProgress(event){
   let audio = event.target;
  let percentComplete = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
  console.log("Progress:", percentComplete + "%");
  range.value = percentComplete;
  range.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}

function resolveLoaded(event){
   return new Promise((resolve)=>{
       resolve(event);
   });
}

function handleAudioLoad(event){
  //console.log('[handleAudioLoad]',event);  
  allSoundLoaded.push(resolveLoaded(event));
}

for(let i = 0; i < soundTracks.length; i++){
   let audio = new Audio(soundTracks[i].sound);
   audio.id = soundTracks[i].id;
   audio.autoplay = false;
   audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleProgress); audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough",handleAudioLoad);
 sounds.push(audio)
}

playbtn.onclick = () => {
   sounds.forEach((sound) => sound.play());
}


range.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const value = +e.target.value;
  const label = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  label.innerHTML = value;
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.range-container {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 18px 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="range"]:focus,input[type="range"]:active {
  outline: none;
  cursor: grabbing !important;
}

input[type="range"] + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

/* Chrome & Safari */
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
  cursor: grab;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 30;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-container">
      <input type="range" name="range" step="10" id="range" min="0" max="100" data-red="yellow"/>
      <label for="range">50</label>
    </div>


<button id="playbtn" style="position: fixed;top: 45px;">Play</button>
```

**Note:**  Please click on Play button to see what is not working in it .

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with network speed. Even four audio files can be loaded at once and don't have to be streamed and synchronized with each other. You however are playing sounds which are varying from 21 seconds length (`medium_bell_ringing_near.ogg`) to over 2 minutes (`afternoon_crickets_long.ogg`). How do you expect the played percentage to synchronize if the sounds are varying this much in playback length?

Comment: @PeterPointer  i was thinking  (Sum of all audio duration  / no of audios)  which will give progress but i'm not sure.

Comment: That would sound very horrible. The 20 second sound would be streched to over 2 minutes. So you mean the playback speed should sync up? Search StackOverflow for related questions: [Controlling audio speed of a mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618845/controlling-audio-speed-of-a-mp3-file) (applies to other audio files as well, I assume).

Comment: You can add both tracks (as `AudioBufferSourceNode`s) to a Web Audio API `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` which will play the tracks in a single `MediaStreamTrack`. You can also create channel mergers in Web Audio API, see [Is it possible to mix multiple audio files on top of each other preferably with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40570114/).

Comment: @guest271314 , These approach seems perfect , i don't know how to implement i will try to get some suggestions from gpt.

Comment: "gpt" is not needed. See the link I posted above.

Comment: @guest271314 , by mistake i missed that , i will check and understand.